# setting datamembers when implementing an abstract class

Tags: c++

So, I have an abstract class A, which I implement in B.

B uses C, and A cannot depend on C. so how do I set it?

I dont want to use a dynamic cast and add a setter to B.

```
class A
{
public:
    virtual void doSomething() const = 0;
}


class C
{}

class B
{
public:
    virtual void doSomething() const { mVar; }  
private:
    C mVar;
}
```

Comment: You would set C when you construct a B. You have to know you're constructing a B when you create it. The users usually only think they're working with an A.

Comment: I will not have C when I construct A...

Comment: You can't construct an A, it's an abstract class.

Comment: What do you mean by "set"? If you're asking how to initialise it, do that in the constructor of `B`. If you're asking how to access it given just a reference to `A`, then you'll either need to use `dynamic_cast` (regardless of whether you want that), or extend the interface of `A` to depend on `C`, or change your design so that you have a reference to `B` when you need one.

Comment: @Steve Sorry, Meant B
(someone commented it here and deleted it?)

Would this work?

 `// No #include "C.h"
 class C;
 class A
 {
  void setC(C*) =0 ;
 }`

Comment: That would work. Then, subclasses would have to implement the `setC()` method. A could then call `setC()` when it was time to set it. Note, though, that calling a virtual method from a constructor might not be a good idea.